# Merge two xml files (add to first file unique element found in second)

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have xml file that contains list of elements, each element contains many subelements, one of them `SHA1` contains unique content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
    <sharedLibrary>
        <SF>
            <FID>One</FID>
            <SHA1>X6PZOW4DLFDUEQU3SW5VPK7MTIF62T2A</SHA1>
        </SF>
        <SF>
            <FID>Two</FID>
            <SHA1>RNKTROE47ZOGJ52Y6QMXPZJPZ56HSXCM</SHA1>
        </SF>
        <SF>
            <FID>And so on</FID>
            <SHA1>4MA633OCAHQC752T5D35LP5TUHQQR3WP</SHA1>
        </SF>
    </sharedLibrary>
</container>
```

Second xml file is similar, but different structure (unique element `sha1`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<containerone>
    <containertwo>
        <shared-file>
            <sha1>X6PZOW4DLFDUEQU3SW5VPK7MTIF62T2A</sha1>
            <file-size>4563154</file-size>
        </shared-file>
        <shared-file>
            <sha1>4MA633OCAHQC752T5D35LP5TUHQQR3WP</sha1>
            <file-size>5267456</file-size>
        </shared-file>
    </containertwo>
</containerone>
```

Resulting file is updated first xml file, that contains new `SIZE` element. It should contain content from `file-size` element if unique element contents are equal. If not, it must contain text `not known`. See expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
    <sharedLibrary>
        <SF>
            <FID>One</FID>
            <SHA1>X6PZOW4DLFDUEQU3SW5VPK7MTIF62T2A</SHA1>
            <SIZE>4563154</SIZE>
        </SF>
        <SF>
            <FID>Two</FID>
            <SHA1>RNKTROE47ZOGJ52Y6QMXPZJPZ56HSXCM</SHA1>
            <SIZE>not known</SIZE>
        </SF>
        <SF>
            <FID>And so on</FID>
            <SHA1>4MA633OCAHQC752T5D35LP5TUHQQR3WP</SHA1>
            <SIZE>5267456</SIZE>
        </SF>
    </sharedLibrary>
</container>
```

XSL stylesheet preferred or another tools that can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="doc2-url" select="'second-file.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($doc2-url)"/>

<xsl:key name="by-sha1" match="containertwo/shared-file" use="sha1"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SF">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <SIZE><xsl:value-of select="(key('by-sha1', SHA1, $doc2)/file-size, 'not known')[1]"/></SIZE>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: where first xml file should be placed? Edit: add this as stylesheet to first file.

Comment: The first XML file should be fed to your XSLT 2.0 processor as the primary input source of the stylesheet. So with Saxon 9 for instance `-s:file1.xml` on the command line.

Comment: Saxon throws an error. SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:param" is not bound.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not post a full stylesheet, I only showed the templates. I will edit to wrap the templates in a proper root element.

Comment: The element type "xsl:copy" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:copy>".